# How to bin a numerical pandas Series into n groups of approximately the same size without qcut?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series, bins

I would like to split my series into exactly n groups (assuming there are at least n distinct values in the series), where the group sizes are approximately equal.

The code needs to be generic, so I cannot know the distribution of the data in advance, hence using `pd.cut` with pre-defined bins is not an option for me.

I tried using `pd.qcut` or `pd.cut` with `pd.Series.quantile` but they all fall short when some value is repeated very often in the series.

For instance, if I want exactly 3 groups:

```
series = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
pd.qcut(series, q=3, duplicates="drop")
```

creates only 2 categories: `Categories (2, interval[float64]): [(0.999, 3.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]`, whereas I would like to get something like `[(0.999, 1.0] < (1.0, 3.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]`.

Is there any way to do this easily with pandas' built-in methods?

Comment: Going by your intervals `[(0.999, 1.0] < (1.0, 3.0] < (3.0, 4.0]]` would result in group sizes of 8, 2 and 4. The sizes are not "approximately equal"

Comment: @CodeDifferent given that I want exactly 3 groups in this case, even though the sizes are quite different, it would be the best possible split (there is no other 3 group split)